Calculation with ONIOM and Grimme's Empirical Dispersion Correction
I am currently working, with Gaussian G09 software, on an ONIOM calculation using the EmpiricalDispersion=GD3 keyword with the B3LYP functional. With the following command line:
# opt freq oniom(b3lyp/gen:uff)=EmbedCharge EmpiricalDispersion=GD3 geom=connectivity

However, I encountered the following error message:
**R6DS8: Unable to choose the **S8 parameter, IExCor= 0 IXCFnc= 0 ScaHFX= 1.000000 IDFTD=3**** 

I found that using mygau with an external keyword may be necessary, as it is explained in this link but I am still facing the same error after trying it.
I would greatly appreciate your guidance on how to resolve this issue.
